# How can I load a single image on Keras, using Google Colab?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I have built a deep learning model which classifies cats and dogs. I have successfully mounted Google drive and trained the images as needed. However, I am trying to make a **single** prediction by uploading **one** image and having Keras make a prediction.

In a regular IDE like Spyder, it's like this :

```
    test_image = image.load_img('image1.jpg',target_size=(64,64))
```

But it throws this error :

```
   Transport endpoint is not connected: 'image1.jpg'
```

I remounted the drive, and then it tells me :

```
    No such file or directory: 'image1.jpg'
```

After that, I played with how I would write the directory on the image.load() method, but ran out of ideas at this point.

Comment: For elaboration, you loaded data on colab from drive. Trained your network which is on a py file. And now you want to make a prediction for a single image. Is that correct?

Comment: Got it fixed, I had the directory written wrong! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the drive, connect with an authentication, then import the files you want and predict using your model. Please check a GitHub gist [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Images_from_gDrive_with_colab.ipynb). You can follow the steps below and let me know if you need any help. Thanks!

```
from google.colab import drive
# This will prompt for authorization.
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Predicting Roses
img=mpimg.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/5602220566_5cdde8fa6c_n.jpg')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
img = tf.expand_dims(img,0) # need this to make batch_shape = 1
img=img/255  # normalizing the image
img=tf.image.resize(img,size=(224, 224)) # resizing image
Prob=loaded_model.predict(img) # prediction
indd=tf.argmax(Prob[0],axis=-1).numpy()
print(tf.argmax(Prob[0],axis=-1).numpy())
print(labels_string[indd])
```